# No internet connection without VPN Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn

I have been using ubuntu for a couple of years but am still pretty inexperienced with Terminal.  I have been using "Private Internet Access" VPN (v75) service for a couple of months now and all of the sudden when I dont have the VPN connected, I cannot access the internet.  I have seen other posts about this but have not had any luck with the solutions (the commands they give seem to assume a lot of working knowledge in terminal, and many no longer work in 17.10).  It appears to be an issue where the DNS is not routing correctly without VPN but I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem using the Private Internet Access(PIA) VPN. After a long time searching in Google for this problem, I found the solution.
Disconnect from VPN and use the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

You might need to reconnect your network in NetworkManager (or reboot) for it to work and resolvconf to update the config.

P.S.: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and version v76 of PIA

Source: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/22079/can-no-longer-connect-to-internet-when-i-exit-pia-app-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score -1):

Kindly restart the network connection with the following commands:

nmcli networking off

nmcli networking on

It will restart the connection, if there is any bug it will be fixed automatically.

Comment: This would probably work as it will reset resolv.conf as in the main answer. But it's a bit too generic of an answer, and there's no explanation as to why it would work. Better answers are more specific and have explanations! Welcome to AU.